# Why is my user not granted root access?

Tags: permissions, root

I ran the below commands and set up a terminal session:

```
karl@i-dev:~$ sudo usermod -aG sudo karl
karl@i-dev:~$ sudo adduser karl sudo
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "ru_RU.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
The user `karl' is already a member of `sudo'.
```

I then logged out and back in and tried to use a root-requiring command:

```
karl@i-dev:~$ docker ps -a
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.26/containers/json?all=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

However, I'm not permitted to. Why was I not granted `root` access on my system?

Answer (score 4):

Your user doesn't automatically get `root` powers by being a member of the `sudo` group. The only thing that confers is the *ability* to run `sudo` and by proxy gain root access.

Docker is looking for one of two things: a user with root-level powers (so only the user account known as `root`, which can be mimicked with `sudo`) or a user that is a member of the `docker` group.

If you'd like to run Docker without `sudo`, it's best to add your user to the `docker` group using the below command:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

A note of warning though for this. By adding yourself to the `docker` group, you can create a Docker container that executes as root. If you grant this container access to your main system's hard drive, you can effectively gain root *without* `sudo`. Think very carefully to ensure that this risk is acceptable first. Also, be sure to only run trusted/audited containers. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface) for a more thorough explanation as to what can go wrong.

---

As for *why* it's designed this way. Instead of just letting a user run any command as root whenever they feel like it, they need to go through the proxy of `sudo`. This prevents a malicious script from getting access to *your* user account, and then taking over the entire system.

It also fits in with Linux's general "permission isolation" model. Instead of running all the time as a privileged user, your day-to-day operation is as an unprivileged normal user which then can be escalated as needed. While you *can* run as `root` 24/7, this is ***highly*** unadvisable because it has the potential to go really wrong really fast.

If you want to escalate to the root user for the rest of your terminal session, just run `sudo -i` or `sudo -s`. Otherwise, just use `sudo` and stay on the safe side.

Comment: Dang! I knew I was doing something very wrong.